# Some API to format a time delta on iOS

Tags: ios

iOS has API's to format a time/date.

However, I have a time delta (meaning endtime - starttime). I want to format it in a format: hh:mm:ss.

Is there iOS API which I can use for this?

Comment: [DateComponentsFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/datecomponentsformatter) will do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DateComponentsFormatter` to convert an `NSTimeInterval` value to a string:

```
let f = DateComponentsFormatter()
f.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute, .second]
f.unitsStyle = .positional
f.zeroFormattingBehavior = .pad
let result = f.string(from: 1000) // "0:16:40"
```